# Fatal FL/SQL error ORA-39565: Message 39565 not found

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle Report to Create Barcode. I import class `oraclebarcode.jar`
I can't use `Chr(13)` for Space Line

```
function CF_1Formula return VarChar2 is
  myFileName varchar2(500);
  result varchar2(500);
  barcodeData VarChar2(50) := '|101'||Chr(13)||'102';
begin
  myFileName := srw.create_temporary_filename;
  barcodemaker.setBarWidthInch(globals.bcobj, 0.005);
  barcodemaker.setBaseCodeData(globals.bcobj,barcodeData);
  barcodemaker.setBarCodeType(globals.bcobj,globals.barcode_to_use);
  barcodemaker.setFullPath(globals.bcobj, myFileName); 
  barcodemaker.renderBarCode(globals.bcobj);
  return(myFileName);
end;
```

I want output

```
|101
102
```

But have Error

> REP-1401: 'cf_1formula': Fatal FL/SQL error occurred ORA-39565:
>   Message 39565 not found; product=RDBMS; facility = ORA

Comment: why you are sure that the problem is from Chr(13) ?

Comment: Did you search for "ora-39565 cf_1formula"? Seems to be a fairly common problem, with your configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Add this :

```
 globals.bcobj := barcodemaker.new();
```

after the begin keyword ....

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Edit the formula column like this 
"function CF_1Formula return VarChar2 is
  myFileName varchar2(500);
  result varchar2(500);
  barcodeData VarChar2(50) := '|101'||Chr(13)||'102';
begin
globals.bcobj := barcodemaker.new(); 
  myFileName := srw.create_temporary_filename;
  barcodemaker.setBarWidthInch(globals.bcobj, 0.005);
  barcodemaker.setBaseCodeData(globals.bcobj,barcodeData);
  barcodemaker.setBarCodeType(globals.bcobj,globals.barcode_to_use);
  barcodemaker.setFullPath(globals.bcobj, myFileName); 
  barcodemaker.renderBarCode(globals.bcobj);
  return(myFileName);
end;"